# Default Path for Database Location when using Alloy Model?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Does anyone know the default Path for database that automatic created by Titanium API, when using Alloy model?

The problem that I try to solve is that I add a new property in the model and when I try to save with Alloy model method. It told me that the table does not have that new column.

If I know the path of the database, in upgrade script I can just alter the table to have a new column.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the location is the same as the Classic. From the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database-section-29004901_WorkingwithaSQLiteDatabase-Creatingadatabase):

> On iOS, the database file that's created is automatically assigned the .sql extension, while on Android no extension is added.
>
> On iOS 5, database files are stored in the app's Private Documents folder (on device); on iOS 4, it is stored in the Application Support/database folder.
>
> On iOS 5.0.1+, the database will be included in any other user data backed up to iCloud. See below for more info.
>
> On Android, the database is created on the internal storage (you could move it, or use the install procedure to put it on external storage). The standard location on internal storage is /data/data/com.example.yourappid/databases/dbname

Alloy's default database is `_alloy_`. But you can choose a different one. See [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations-section-36739597_AlloySyncAdaptersandMigrations-SQLiteSyncAdapter).

Last, I suggest you use Alloy's db migration than writing your own script to handle it. See [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations-section-36739597_AlloySyncAdaptersandMigrations-Migrations).